# How to test Laravel / Sanctum endpoint with CSRF tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-sanctum

I have a headless laravel instance connected to a SPA on a subdomain.  As my first test, I want to see a 401 when trying retrieve user data from the api without being logged in.  My api path is defined as the following:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', 'UserAccountController@get_profile');
```

I know a CSRF token is needed before a user can successfully connect to the application, but I'm unsure how to include that in my test process as shown below

```
public function testExample()
{
    $response = $this->get('/api/user');
    $response->assertStatus(401); //  getting a 500 instead
}
```

In the [Sanctum testing](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#testing) portion of the documentation, I see the following method:

```
Sanctum::actingAs( factory(User::class)->create(), ['view-tasks'] );
```

The issue here for me is that I don't want to attempt to load this path as a user, I want to know how to simulate a client machine that has the token, but isn't logged in.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per "Nick" in the laravel slack chat, I needed to change the request to the following:

```
public function testExample()
{
    $response = $this->getJson('/api/user');
    $response->assertStatus(401);
}
```

The `get()` assumes you’re doing a normal request, whereas `getJSON()` handles the necessary header settings.  This call returned the 401 in the same way I see in my application.

Further, the following could be used to test a hypothetical JSON response

```
$response->assertJson([
  "message" => "User Unauthorized"
]);
```